# sed erasing everything instead of changing single field

Tags: shell, sed

hi i have this code that is meant to update a single field title but it ended with it erasing everything. need some help please

BookDB.txt:

```
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:1:1
Weapon X:Stan Lee:1:1:1
Weapon X:stan lim:1:1:1
```

```
function update_title
{
   echo "Title: "
   read title
   echo "Author: "
   read author
   grep -iqs "$title:$author:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found!"
   echo "New Title: "
   read title_new   
   sed -i "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Comment: Add some lines of BookDB.txt.

Comment: Why are you using `|| tee`?

Comment: @Cyrus i have added some lines

Comment: @anubhava i use || tee so that whatever command is done on the terminal will apply to the .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this , because first field is definitely the title so you have to put title infront

```
sed -i "/^$title:$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

### Answer for Revised Question

The `sed` command needs to be changed because the title comes first on the line, not the author. Also the `tee` command removed for the same reasons as explained below.  Thus, define the function as follows:

```
update_title () 
{ 
    echo "Title: ";
    read title;
    echo "Author: ";
    read author;
    grep -iqs "$title:$author:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found!";
    echo "New Title: ";
    read title_new;
    sed -i "/:$author:/ s/^$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

As an example, invoke the function:

```
$ update_title 
Title: 
Weapon X
Author: 
Stan Lee
Book Found!
New Title: 
Weapon XYZ
Book Title has been updated sucessfully!
```

The result is:

```
$ cat BookDB.txt 
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:1:1
Weapon XYZ:Stan Lee:1:1:1
Weapon X:stan lim:1:1:1
```

### Answer for Original Question

Replace:

```
sed -i "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
```

With this:

```
sed -i "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
```

The first line asks `sed` to rewrite `BookDB.txt` in place.  It then asks `tee` to overwrite the same file.  The solution is to do the first only.

#### Explanation

Commands such as:

```
sed 's/old/new/' file >file
```

or:

```
sed 's/old/new/' file | tee file
```

will be unreliable.  They attempt to read from a file while writing to it at the same time.  Depending on how files are buffered, this type of command may occasionally work but are never to be trusted.

`sed -i` is specifically designed to avoid this issue.  It writes to a temporary file and, after all changes have been successfully save, then overwrites the source file.

#### Example

Let's define this function:

```
function update_title
{
   echo "Title: "
   read title
   echo "Author: "
   read author
   grep -iqs "$title:$author:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found!"
   echo "New Title: "
   read title_new   
   sed -i "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Now, let's use it:

```
$ cat BookDB.txt 
Tim:Old Title:
Tom:Older Title:
$ update_title 
Title: 
Old Title
Author: 
Tim
New Title: 
New Title
Book Title has been updated sucessfully!
$ cat BookDB.txt 
Tim:New Title:
Tom:Older Title:
```

The old title was successfully replaced.

#### Warning

This function substitutes shell variables directly into `sed` commands.  If the user is unaware of the power of sed-active characters, the results may be surprising.

As an example:

```
$ update_title 
Title: 
.*
Author: 
Tim
New Title: 
This & That
Book Title has been updated sucessfully!
```

Now, observe the new file:

```
$ cat BookDB.txt 
This Tim:New Title: That
Tom:Older Title:
```

#### OSX

On OSX, the `-i` option to `sed` requires an argument.  For OSX, and possibly other BSD platforms, replace the `sed` line in the function definition with:

```
   sed -i .bak "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
```

Or,

```
   sed -i "" "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_new/" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Title has been updated sucessfully!"
```

Comment: changed the line but nothing happen and tee is supposed to edit file based on what i do on terminal thats why i'm stuck :(

Comment: @Ken What does "nothing happen" mean?  Was the file still erased?  Is the file in its original form unchanged?  Or?

Comment: it ran but the file remain unchanged

Comment: That means that it didn't find a line in the file containing `$author:` which also had the text `$title`.  They have to match _exactly_.  Remember also that, by default, sed's matches are case-sensitive.

Comment: hi i went and retry it and i matched every single character there is but i still won't work nothing changed

Comment: @Ken I added an example that I used to test the code.  As you can see, it worked for me.  Please copy and paste my example and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Ken Are you on a Mac (OSX)?  If so, the syntax will be a little different.

Comment: i'm using VMware ubuntu yeah i'll copy and paste again and try thx!

Comment: It works if i remove the $author but that would defeat the purpose of it working if there are duplicate titles

Comment: @Ken Your code was written assuming that the author field came first on a line.  The newly added sample `BookDB.txt` has the title first and author second.  Is the sample `BookDB.txt` correct?

Comment: Yes. That is the file that i used. The title is supposed to be the first field, author second. So do i need to change my code for that?

Comment: @Ken The `^` in the `sed` command only matches at the beginning of a line.  See the revised answer for code for the case that the line begins with the title, not the author.